# Rendering string from MYSQL in div removes all white space

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to render a string with spaces and line spaces in it.

When I render the string as a value on an input, the spaces show as expected.

```
<textarea
  rows={15}
  value={content}
/>
```

When I render the string in a div, all of the white spaces are removed.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />
```

How can I render a string in the div without removing the white space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply `white-space: pre-wrap;` style to your `div`, so the white spaces will be displayed